# Creating Kubernetes TLS assets before i know public and private IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kubernetes, coreos

Following https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/getting-started.html , i wanted to generate my TLS assets for my kubernetes cluster.
My plan to push those keys via cloud-config to the aws-api to create EC2 instances won't work, because i won't know the public and private IPs of those instances in advance.

I though about moving the ca cert to the instances via the cloud-config, where i then, generate those assets from a script run by a systemd unit file. Biggest concern here is that i don't want to put a ca root cert into a cloud config.

Does anyone have a solution to this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to how kube-aws does it, I can set my **api-server conf** like this:

```
[req]
req_extensions = v3_req
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
[req_distinguished_name]
[ v3_req ]
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = kubernetes
DNS.2 = kubernetes.default
DNS.3 = kubernetes.default.svc
DNS.4 = kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
DNS.5 = kubernetes.mydomain.de
IP.1 = 10.3.0.1
```

to the "minimal config file" i added

- My public DNS `DNS.5 = kubernetes.mydomain.de`
- I omit the MASTER_HOST IP address because I can instead use the FQDN (kubernetes.mydomain.de) to get to that IP
- The "K8S_SERVICE_IP", which should be the first IP of my internal IP range (10.3.0.0/24): `IP.2 = 10.3.0.1`

The **worker conf** looks like this:

```
[req]
req_extensions = v3_req
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
[req_distinguished_name]
[ v3_req ]
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = *.*.cluster.internal
```

The trick here is to set the SAN as a wildcard `*.*.cluster.internal`. This way all the workers verify with that cert on the internal network and I don't have to set the specific IP address.